# Global Error Reporting for CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I work for a very large organization.  We have over 500 builds on our CI server with thousands of components, generating ridiculously large log files.  As someone who has to manage failures, I find it to be quite a burden to drill down into a build log looking for errors, hit the back button a bunch, re-sort everything by build status, scroll down to the next app, rinse n' repeat.

I am looking for a way to develop a custom report that would show me all failures of all apps on the server, as well as details of each error right there on that single page.  This sounds like something that should already exist but after an hour on Google I can't find anything.

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you can set failed build notification, so that you will receive notifications for failed build and i think we can send the build log as an attachment.